# How to do keypress of "@" in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to do the following:

```
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key['N'], null, null, 0)
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key['@'], null, null, 0)
```

But the `@` symbol is not working. How would I enter in `@` in the above?

Here is the event I am trying to use: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html

Comment: Can't you use event.which[50] ( corresponds to '@' ) instead of event.key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"@" and "N" are normal *characters* on the keyboard so you can simply pass them as string:

```
page.sendEvent('keypress', 'N');
page.sendEvent('keypress', '@');
```

or even

```
page.sendEvent('keypress', 'N@');
```

Since you're not setting any modifier, you can remove the optional values of `sendEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
// https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a#diff-e52366857ac302b6d40c78a058758a0aR358
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key['At'], null, null, 0);
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesn't do anything for me.